# How to tell if java application is close to running out of memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

My simple goal: monitor the memory usage of a Java application so I can be warned when the application is getting dangerously close to throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Yes, simple to state, but coming up with a correct solution seems very complicated. Some of the complicating factors are:

- There are different heap regions, each of which can throw an `OutOfMemoryError`:

  - The `permgen` space, which has it's own size limit (set via `-XX:MaxPermSize=`)
  - The overall heap space (set via `-Xmx`)
- The VM may allocate almost all of the heap before bothering to garbage collect. If the application uses a lot of soft references, then in fact this will surely happen. So just a high heap allocation percentage does not imply the application is near to throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`.
- It would be nice if `System.gc()` guaranteed that the VM would reclaim all possibly reclaimable object (unreferenced and/or weakly referenced object), but it doesn't. So invoking `System.gc()` and then `Runtime.freeMemory()` is not reliable.
- Objects that are queued for finalization take up memory, but (usually) are freed after they are finalized. So whether the finalizer thread has gotten to them or not affects the (apparent) memory usage (does the VM run the finalizer as a last desparate act before throwing OOM? [Doesn't look like it.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4239841))
- Native code takes up memory as well and too much usage of it can lead to OOM (this is not a likely case in my specific application, but does add another complication to the overall picture).

So what is a good and reliable way to answer the question: **Is my Java application getting to throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`?**

Put another way, suppose application version X runs fine and has no memory leak, but version X + 1 has a slow unrecognized memory leak. I'd like to be alerted by this monitoring before version X + 1 throws an `OutOfMemoryError`, but I'd like the exact same monitoring to not give false positives for version X. There may be some tuning required in setting up this monitoring - that's OK.

One possible answer might be something like: what is the maximum, over the past N "full" GC runs, of the heap utilization immediately after the GC run? If this value exceeds X% of the total allocated memory, then sound the alarms.

The idea is to determine "application memory usage" in simple number like a percentage, or even something like LOW, MEDIUM, or HIGH, and then monitor this value.

The [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) command gives lots of relevant information, the problem is boiling it down to a simple answer and avoiding false positives (or negatives) caused by the complicating factors listed above.

Comment: There may be heuristics is your application is not subject to "memory outbursts", but it will be as reliable as heuristics go -- not much, then better, then acceptable, then good enough as heuristics are fine tuned. But good?

Answer (score 7):

If you watch a memory graph of a long-running application (collected with a tool like jconsole, for example) you'll see a characteristic sawtooth pattern: memory usage climbs, then is GC'd back to a baseline, and then it climbs again. For a healthy app, the peaks and valleys are in two straight horizontal lines. For a leaking app, though, the baseline climbs. That's really what you need to watch for: if each successive GC is less effective than the last, then something is rotten in Denmark.

Comment: This is a good general guideline, but I'm currently looking at a situation where an app has this "climbing sawtooth" pattern. The moment it hits 100%, the garbage collector suddenly gets really aggressive and drops the usage back to ~20%. This is incredibly annoying because we have no idea if 99.99% memory usage means imminent failure or nothing is wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

Search [the Oracle docs page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/mxbeans.html) for the term `Detecting Low Memory` and `Threshold Notifications` -- you may be able to devise some alert system based upon built-in MXBeans.  Garbage collection appears to be a focus of at least some of the metrics collection.